# Binary operator in loki

Tags: grafana, grafana-loki, logql

Do binary operators for Loki queries exist?
Is there a workaround to achieve something as this?

```
{job="myService"} 
  |~"AI Unable to update the session state in"
  OR 
  |~"Database Write Error"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't do that but you can do, for example, the following:

```
{job="myService"} |~ "AI Unable to update the session state in|Database Write Error"
```

Or the following:

```
count_over_time({job="myService"} |~ "AI Unable to update the session state in" [1h])
or
count_over_time({job="myService"} |~ "Database Write Error" [1h])
```